# How can I determine if a user cancels a CredentialsPicker?

Tags: windows-8

How can I determine if a user cancels a `CredentialsPicker`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in the [Credential Picker sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Credential-picker-sample-30fcba2e). Using scenario 1, for example, you'll see that cancelation of the picker will return a [CredentialPickerResults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.ui.credentialpickerresults.aspx) object (in the promise results or from the API in C#), in which the ErrorCode property (errorCode in JS) will contain x800704c7 which is the Win32 error code ERROR_CANCELLED.

If for some reason the credential picker cannot be displayed, that would generate an error from the credential picker itself (and be picked up by an error handler give to a promise.then). The case you're describing is that the credential picker succeeded, but the user canceled.

Comment: Thanks! [The MSDN Error Codes page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#error_cancelled) says the code should be 0x4c7. Do you know why it has the extra four bits set? Should I be ignoring the two most significant bytes?